# Automatically highlighting all occurrences of a regular expression on a web page

Tags: web-browser, regex

I once found a web application that was able to highlight all occurrences of a regular expression on a web page, but I can't find it now. Are there any other web applications that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of Google searching, I [found the bookmarklet that I was looking for](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2010/09/regular-expression-search-bookmarklet.html).

In case this link becomes broken, I have posted the bookmarklet's source code here:

```
javascript:if(typeof(searches)=='undefined'){var searches=0;};(function(){var count=0,text,regexp;text=prompt('Search regex:','');if(text==null||text.length==0)return;try{regexp=new RegExp(text,'i');}catch(er){alert('Unable to create regular expression using text \''+text+'\'.\n\n'+er);return;}function searchWithinNode(node,re){var pos,skip,acronym,middlebit,endbit,middleclone;skip=0;if(node.nodeType==3){pos=node.data.search(re);if(pos>=0){acronym=document.createElement('ACRONYM');acronym.title='Search '+(searches+1)+': '+re.toString();acronym.style.backgroundColor=backColor;acronym.style.borderTop='1px solid '+borderColor;acronym.style.borderBottom='1px solid '+borderColor;acronym.style.fontWeight='bold';acronym.style.color=borderColor;middlebit=node.splitText(pos);endbit=middlebit.splitText(RegExp.lastMatch.length);middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);acronym.appendChild(middleclone);middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(acronym,middlebit);count++;skip=1;}}else if(node.nodeType==1&&node.childNodes&&node.tagName.toUpperCase()!='SCRIPT'&&node.tagName.toUpperCase!='STYLE')for(var child=0;child<node.childNodes.length;++child)child=child+searchWithinNode(node.childNodes[child],re);return skip;}var borderColor='#'+(searches+8).toString(2).substr(-3).replace(/0/g,'3').replace(/1/g,'6');var backColor=borderColor .replace(/3/g,'c').replace(/6/g,'f');if(searches%2516/8>=1){var tempColor=borderColor;borderColor=backColor;backColor=tempColor;}searchWithinNode(document.body,regexp);window.status='Found '+count+' match'+(count==1?'':'es')+' for '+regexp+'.';if(count>0)searches++;})();
```

Comment: You have to wait 2 days, IIRC, before you can accept your own answer. But please do as it will help future searchers (and thanks for a good utility)